# What is the usual meaning of the notation $ \| f \|_{C^k (A)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, notation

If $f \in C^k ( \mathbb R)$ and $A \subset \mathbb R$, what is the usual meaning of the notation below?
$$ \| f \|_{C^k (A)} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you meant $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, the notation usually means
$$\|f\|_{C^k(A)}=\|f\|+\|f'\|+\cdots+\|f^{(k)}\|$$
where $f^{(i)}$ is the $i$th derivative of $f$, and where for a function $g:A\to\mathbb{R}$, the notation $\|g\|$ refers to the sup norm:
$$\|g\|=\sup_{x\in A} \,|g(x)|$$
I've also seen the definition
$$\|f\|_{C^k(A)}=\max\left\{\|f\|,\|f'\|,\ldots,\|f^{(k)}\|\right\}$$
which (if I remember correctly) induces the same topology.

Comment: Oh thank you it was just a sup.

Comment: Well, it's the sum of the sup-norms of the function itself, its first derivative, second derivative, etc., and $k$th derivative.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much.

Comment: As a remark, both norms you mention do in fact induce the same topology because the first norm is $\|(\|f\|, \|f'\|, ..., \|f^{(k)}\|)\|_\infty$, the second is $\|(\|f\|, \|f'\|, ..., \|f^{(k)}\|)\|_1$ and all norms on a finite dimensional space are equivalent.